# Docker returning 405 (Not Allowed) when requesting assets in RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, deployment

I'm building the docker containers for a Ruby on Rails project but when it finishes building all the assets return 405 (Not Allowed) when requesting them in my local computer and 404 (not found) in the production server.

Development:

[image: development]

Production:

[image: production]

I already reinstalled docker but I'm getting the same result.

UPDATE:

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1-alpine3.7

RUN apk add --update build-base nodejs tzdata libxml2-dev postgresql-dev postgresql-client git less
RUN apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies make g++

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install --binstubs
RUN apk del build-dependencies && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*


COPY . ./
```

This is my docker-composer:

```
version: '3'
services:
  setup:
    image: minecraft.grumpyzombies.com/pcz-store
    volumes:
      - /root/apps/pcz-store/uploads:/myapp/public/uploads
      - /root/apps/pcz-store/assets:/myapp/public/assets
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=production
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE=b84b5c15aa42b2be2290d4bb330e3ce4ec0d39847babca3c6189f1721e7bc636bd60d7d7cc0fb156d4845f403dfa5432448435926b79c913133bbf75d1cd498e
    restart: on-failure
    command: docker/assets_precompile.sh
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - /root/apps/pcz-store/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    image: minecraft.grumpyzombies.com/pcz-store
    volumes:
      - /root/apps/pcz-store/uploads:/myapp/public/uploads
      - /root/apps/pcz-store/assets:/myapp/public/assets
    depends_on:
      - setup
      - db
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=production
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE=b84b5c15aa42b2be2290d4bb330e3ce4ec0d39847babca3c6189f1721e7bc636bd60d7d7cc0fb156d4845f403dfa5432448435926b79c913133bbf75d1cd498e
    command: docker/entrypoint.sh
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    image: minecraft.grumpyzombies.com/pcznginx
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /root/apps/pcz-store/assets:/var/www/myapp/public/assets
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
    - cluster.name=docker-cluster
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    privileged: true
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
    command: su -c ./bin/elasticsearch elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - web
      - db
```

Second update:

This is what I get when I run: `ls -lart /var/www/myapp/public/assets` in the nginx container.

```
root@pcz-store:~# docker exec -it d47aecf71c05 sh
/var/www/myapp # ls -lart /var/www/myapp/public/assets
total 3624
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          6760 Feb 28 21:59 terms_conditions_icon-34d7728acea9739e5663475fa58bb00070eada9dbf035f396ffa9ebf9d61a695.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          7717 Feb 28 21:59 shipping_icon-9c050291621972a805212663d85d85ce16f4ab4bac1b6df26fb4c81111b04954.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2194 Feb 28 21:59 search_btn-1337ebd34122bf832ef77c294a9a0cfacc01eec14abacd672760d4534f66309f.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          6323 Feb 28 21:59 pcz_small_logo-f2cc1d44bb90b448b9b88348664a8384b378a257ab2c0bf8b0a3858f6a68150d.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2336 Feb 28 21:59 filter_menu-32653a4203b8bf0d5de68691de26f9c0b590018b5d8c34e8108dff55ca0a8f28.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1090 Feb 28 21:59 card_with_items-14c488398004329490b11e22dd425126e726bb724d8997482011fb8d53681d10.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5494 Feb 28 21:59 card_payment_icon-506681ad792fbceb514fe8dcb48c48b1ad552c1a430bb83cb8fd0a72bbfeed6f.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           771 Feb 28 21:59 card-8ac603143bafe864976639270b0e7218a40c4fc7d7bb14d8d1eaa0f4b5a96e14.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          6338 May  6 21:57 pcz_logo_blue-df8681f5d301079d4b14a0f5f61a64015fa3005e665fcb6d6efac10d541bfba9.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          7494 May  6 21:57 pcz_logo_2-f65fe6b96c6cb86a5546e2c96db79db837b97c9ebe2ac80a928ca30604890709.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          6009 May  6 21:57 pcz_logo-30a5ea591292bd780af89c4070b9f0e9bee3feccee260e8767611f88d3129813.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4143 May  6 21:57 menu_icon-63b742c78ceea89533f5e47f71cf7694a7603f182618b8b91b2f2e8c9f5cad88.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1975 May  6 21:57 card_white_with_items-a27394bbc2b5b6687aaad72dc2ae1caadbac4670e91f644fb6bf179da664a41e.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1834 May  6 21:57 card_white-29b18b65b693a5470c4dc25503c7817e9ee655d0a92b5fced902dcdcde038c72.png
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May  8 17:31 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         85634 May  9 18:30 login_background-db8d4fb738db92fa96201ae66011a35566030de51a44b3ffbd47d5f5b07d5614.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         91419 May  9 18:30 admin-b99dedd500b2b0074741175197a8f478fa8efec08effdc1ae28ecc5c16c81460.css.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        575024 May  9 18:30 admin-b99dedd500b2b0074741175197a8f478fa8efec08effdc1ae28ecc5c16c81460.css
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         98024 May  9 18:33 fontawesome-webfont-ba0c59deb5450f5cb41b3f93609ee2d0d995415877ddfa223e8a8a7533474f07.woff
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        134485 May  9 18:33 fontawesome-webfont-ad6157926c1622ba4e1d03d478f1541368524bfc46f51e42fe0d945f7ef323e4.svg.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        444379 May  9 18:33 fontawesome-webfont-ad6157926c1622ba4e1d03d478f1541368524bfc46f51e42fe0d945f7ef323e4.svg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         98106 May  9 18:33 fontawesome-webfont-aa58f33f239a0fb02f5c7a6c45c043d7a9ac9a093335806694ecd6d4edc0d6a8.ttf.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        165548 May  9 18:33 fontawesome-webfont-aa58f33f239a0fb02f5c7a6c45c043d7a9ac9a093335806694ecd6d4edc0d6a8.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         98200 May  9 18:33 fontawesome-webfont-7bfcab6db99d5cfbf1705ca0536ddc78585432cc5fa41bbd7ad0f009033b2979.eot.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        165742 May  9 18:33 fontawesome-webfont-7bfcab6db99d5cfbf1705ca0536ddc78585432cc5fa41bbd7ad0f009033b2979.eot
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         77160 May  9 18:33 fontawesome-webfont-2adefcbc041e7d18fcf2d417879dc5a09997aa64d675b7a3c4b6ce33da13f3fe.woff2
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         34260 May  9 18:33 application-ff019001d3b7f91bae6da2b446df296fa8f0b1e8d236c5de4449aa65f683f644.css.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        199990 May  9 18:33 application-ff019001d3b7f91bae6da2b446df296fa8f0b1e8d236c5de4449aa65f683f644.css
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         69867 May  9 18:33 application-9fb13c3411be138ab44f1c4ab79a3325374cb7bdc733423b1d0930a4051030d3.js.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        235590 May  9 18:33 application-9fb13c3411be138ab44f1c4ab79a3325374cb7bdc733423b1d0930a4051030d3.js
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        212342 May  9 18:33 admin-66de62e1b8d9a65dfa06311ddcf46d9b39d8ea9c52989f89886ed8a036077d75.js.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        768369 May  9 18:33 admin-66de62e1b8d9a65dfa06311ddcf46d9b39d8ea9c52989f89886ed8a036077d75.js
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 13 03:27 img
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 13 03:27 font-awesome
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         21847 May 13 03:27 .sprockets-manifest-757ca632d463d59749404f32eb6c13db.json
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 May 13 03:27 .
```

Comment: I sure it is not Docker returning those codes but your application. What is your setup (Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, folder structure, host os)? Can you post those resources as well?

Comment: check the files permissions in the resulting image

Comment: @Mihai I posted the dockerfile and the docker-compose file. Thanks!

Comment: @danielavila From what I understand the assets end-up first in the host volume and then are mounted in the nginx container at path: /var/www/myapp/public/assets? Is that correct? Can you open a shell inside the nginx container and run "ls -lart /var/www/myapp/public/assets"? I assume that the files giving the errors should be served from "/var/www/myapp/public/assets" by nginx but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Mihai this is what I get when I run `ls -lart /var/www/myapp/public/assets` in the nginx container.

Comment: Can you answer the rest of the questions as well? From what I see the files are readable and they should be picked if nginx was correctly configured. Do you have the project on github or so where I can have a look? There are too many configuration files to check here...